# the formula in google sheet on request should sort the list by the values ​of cell C and by letters from cell A

Tags: google-sheets

```
=QUERY(A2:C100, "SELECT * WHERE A<>'' ORDER BY CASE WHEN A LIKE '%EU%' AND C<>'' THEN 1 WHEN A LIKE '%EU%' AND C='' THEN 2 WHEN A LIKE '%UA%' AND C<>'' THEN 3 WHEN A LIKE '%UA%' AND C='' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END, C, A")
```

This formula selects all rows in the range `A1:C100` where the value in column A is not empty, and sorts them based on the following criteria:

1. If column A contains "EU" and column C is not empty, sort first.
2. If column A contains "EU" and column C is empty, sort second.
3. If column A contains "UA" and column C is not empty, sort third.
4. If column A contains "UA" and column C is empty, sort fourth.

For all other rows, sort last.

The formula should sort the list by the values ​​of cell C and by letters from cell A must work but...#ERROR! please help

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Post few sample data then show your desired output and explain in brief.

Answer (score 0):

The QUERY language does not support CASE statements

Instead you can construct a sort column within your dataset and refer to it within the ORDER BY clause.  For example:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:C100,IF((IFERROR(FIND("EU",A2:A100),0)>0)*(C2:C100<>""),1,IF((IFERROR(FIND("EU",A2:A100),0)>0)*(C2:C100=""),2,IF((IFERROR(FIND("UA",A2:A100),0)>0)*(C2:C100<>""),3,IF((IFERROR(FIND("UA",A2:A100),0)>0)*(C2:C100=""),4,5))))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col1<>'' ORDER BY Col4, Col3, Col1"))`

This demo sheet shows it working: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_H18HLClRtUddTo7MjhnWibxq3Wg33Bhhx28TkHvj2k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool! it`s what do you need!